# Using multirow and column type X (from tabularx) in a table

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, overlap

I'm trying to reproduce this table:

[image]

However, when I try it in LaTeX, the last column overlaps the cells

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
        \textbf{Grupo} & \textbf{Categorias} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Principais\\representantes}} & \textbf{Função} \\
        Algas & Diatomáceas & Asterionella, Synedra & \multirow{5}{\hsize}{Dada sua capacidade de fotosíntese, são produtores primários. Absorbem CO2, nitratos e fosfatos e produzem oxigênio. O oxigênio reage com impurezas orgânicas, tornando-as mais facilmete assimiláveis pelas algas e outros organismos} \\
        & Cianobactérias & Microcystis &  \\
        & Algas móveis & Chlamydomonas, Navicula &  \\
        & Algas planctônicas & Chlorella, Scenedesmus &  \\
        & Algas filamentosas & Spirogyra, Tribonema &  \\
        Bactérias &       & Enterobacteriales, Vibrionales & Oxidam e mineralizam parte da matéria orgânica e alimentam alguns organismos superiores como protozoarios e invertebrados \\
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want? I only added a convenient `\addlinespace`, and slightly simplified the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm, showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}\renewcommand{\theadalign}{lc}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
        \thead{Grupo} & \thead{Categorias} & \thead{Principais\\representantes} & \thead{Função} \\
\addlinespace
        Algas & Diatomáceas & Asterionella, Synedra & \multirow{5}{\hsize}{Dada sua capacidade de fotosíntese, são produtores primários. Absorbem CO2, nitratos e fosfatos e produzem oxigênio. O oxigênio reage com impurezas orgânicas, tornando-as mais facilmete assimiláveis pelas algas e outros organismos} \\
        & Cianobactérias & Microcystis & \\
        & Algas móveis & Chlamydomonas, Navicula & \\
        & Algas planctônicas & Chlorella, Scenedesmus & \\
        & Algas filamentosas & Spirogyra, Tribonema & \\
\addlinespace[10ex]
        Bactérias & & Enterobacteriales, Vibrionales & Oxidam e mineralizam parte da matéria orgânica e alimentam alguns organismos superiores como protozoarios e invertebrados \\
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]